# kotlin avoiding deep nesting of `let` inside `let`

Tags: kotlin, coding-style

Is there a way to avoid next constructions? A way to check for null without adding intendation to code? I mean like `if (variableOne == null) return` but in cool and awesome koltin style?

```
variableOne?.let{
    // ....

    variableTwo?.let {
        // ...

        variableThree?.let {
            // ...

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Afaik there isn't an official/nicer way to do that.
It has been long discussed on the kotlin discuss:
https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/kotlin-null-check-for-multiple-nullable-vars/1946/47
In that thread there are a few solutions/ideas.

Answer (score 2):

Use local variables and smart-casting.

```
val lVariable1 = variable1
val lVariable2 = variable2
val lVariable3 = variable3
if (lVariable1 != null &&
        lVariable2 != null &&
        lVariable3 != null) {
    // Use local variables here
}
```

Comment: what if you are using var and not val ? smart cast will not work

Comment: @PedroAGSantos That’s what these local variables are for. Inside the braces you can use the smart-casted local variables to read the values but you can still write to the read-write member properties if you need to.

Comment: so you make them immutable to be able to make a smart cast

Comment: You could say that, or you could say you make them local to be able to smart cast. Local `var`s can be smart cast because they aren't going to be accessed outside the local scope.

Answer (score 2):

***Use plain old `if` `statements`, it is recommended by the core kotlin team members***, so in your case

```
if(variableOne != null && variableTwo != null && variableThree != null){
    //Do something
}
```

Following is relevant text from [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> When you need to check multiple values for null, you can use nested
>   let calls to handle them. ***But in most cases, such code ends up fairly
>   verbose and hard to follow. It’s generally easier to use a regular if
>   expression to check all the values together.***

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no *awesome* way (until functions with multiple receivers are added into Kotlin). There are two options to avoid this callback hell:

1. Use `if (variableOne == null) return` statements.
2. Create a helper function like this:

```
fun <A : Any, B : Any, C : Any> runIfNotNull(a: A?, b: B?, c: C?, block: (A, B, C) -> 
Unit) {
    if (a != null && b != null && c != null) block(a, b, c)
}
```

So you can use it like this:

```
runIfNotNull(nullableOne, nullableTwo, nullableThree) { notNullOne, notNullTwo, notNullThree ->
    doSomething(notNullOne, notNullTwo, notNullThree)
}
```

And you will have to create similar functions for every count of arguments you would need.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to chain them like this:

```
variableOne?.let {
    /* "it" refers to variableOne, 
       do some stuff with it */

    variableTwo
}?.let {
    /* "it" refers to variableTwo,
       do some stuff with it */

    variableThree
}?.let {
    /* "it" refers to variableThree,
       do some stuff with it  */
}
```